# How do I get an input value into Angular's $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

I'm new to Angular, and I am trying to do something really basic. Here is a part of a view (all angular files are added elsewhere) :

```
 <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
    <input type='text' ng-model='id'>
 </div>
```

And here is my controller :

```
 module.controller('ctrl',['$scope', function ($scope) {

    // get the scope value here
}]);
```

What I'm trying to do is really simple. I'd like to use the input value. I tried something like `$scope.data = []` and `$scope.data.push($scope.id)` to create an array with the scope's value, but it didn't work. When I tried to display the value, I got an 'undefined' on the console.

Do you guys have any idea ?

Edit : The view also has a button with the `ng-click` directive which trigger the controller's function where I try to get my value.

Comment: Did you type anything into the `input`?

Comment: I type something, and (I didn't write it on the original post) I have a button, with an `ng-click` directive linked to a function in the controller.

Comment: Edit the title of the question so that it states the problem you're facing, "Just trying to do some basic stuff with AngularJS's ngModel" tells me nothing. You wouldn't ask your parent "I'm trying to do some cooking with a stove" ... "okay, what's the question? What are you cooking? What's the problem?".

Comment: I would add the `ng-click` to the question. Post the code "as-is" - not a close representation... little errors can looks like big problems.

Comment: Check my blog post. It could be useful for you: http://www.espeo.pl/angularjs-how-properly-use-watch-and-watchcollection/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The value will automatically be added to the `$scope`, but you have to type something into the `input` element.

That said, you need to trigger something to get this value.  For example, where you have your comment `// get the scope value here` -- this is triggered as soon as the controller is initialized and never called again; so, it's going to log undefined at that time.  However, if you set it to a button click, or something, you will see it's available:

```
<div ng-controller='ctrl'>
   <input type='text' ng-model='id'>
   <button ng-click="logId()">Log ID</button>
</div>
```

And your controller:

```
module.controller('ctrl',['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.logId = function() {
        console.log($scope.id);
    }
}]);
```

Now type something into the input and click the button.

Comment: Hmm, my bad, I forgot to mention it. I have a button on the view, with an `ng-click` directive linked to a function in the controller to trigger it. I'll add it to the original post !

Comment: Can you provide a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com) or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that doesn't work?  The code I provided works fine: http://jsbin.com/wuhiciwibi/1/edit?html,js,console,output @Arhyaa

Comment: I switch from `angular.min.js` to `angular.js` in the main view, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need it in array, just do this in your controller:

`$scope.data = [0];`

and in HTML do
`<input type="text" ng-model="data[0]">`

It will fill that array value automaticaly as you type something in INPUT, id will be always at first position in array.

Or you can handle it with object
In controller:
`$scope.data = {};`

in HTML `<input type="text" ng-model="data.id">`